# Wireless connection on windows 8 after reboot to SMWN

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking, safe-mode

I've been trying to find some information on this but good old google shows me nothing useful, I was looking for a way that I can tell windows to remain connected to the wireless network after is rebooted to SMWN, as it use to do back in previous versions, now when it restarts the connection is cut and you have to manually reconnect

Any ideas on what needs to be changed to make this work?